# Error using onClickListener (Intent)

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Well, I'm trying to create an intent on a "login.java" the code is :

```
 Button btEntrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSingIn);
    btEntrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i;
            i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);


        }
    });
```

But it says that I can't go to the other activity saying this :

> Error:(24, 21) error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(,Class)
>       constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
>       (argument mismatch;  cannot be converted to String)
>       constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class) is not applicable
>       (argument mismatch;  cannot be converted to Context)

and...

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
>   Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: Change the i=new Intent(YourActivityName.this,MainActivity.class);

Comment: @sufiyan your answer worked perfectly like all of the rest.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Just a few lines to explain the reason why `this` does not work in:

```
i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class)
```

The intent is created inside another class, here an anonymous inner class `OnClickListener`. Thus `this` does not refer the instance of your Activity (or Context) as intended but the instance of your anonymous inner class `OnClickListener`.

So you should provide the correct context of your class.

```
i = new Intent(YourClassName.this, MainActivity.class)
```

Comment: Another option is: i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);

Answer (score 6):

use 
if you want to send it from `login.java` to `mainactivity.class` use

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(login.this,Mainactivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

updated code in to your activity

```
Button btEntrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSingIn);
 btEntrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i;
        i = new Intent(login.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);


    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

try using

```
Intent i = new Intent(login.this, mainActivity.class);
```

hope this helps

Answer (score -2):

Did you add manifest.xml or try this code ?
`Intent i = new Intent(login.this,mainActivity.class);`