# I need call another activity automatic, more not know where to put code, facebook login

Tags: java, android, facebook, sdk

Sorry my english ! need call another activity automatic, more not know where to put  code, "facebook login sdk" It how is code, "startActivity" not function

```
/**  * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.  */ 
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

private TextView mTextDetails;
private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;
private AccessTokenTracker mTokenTracker;
private ProfileTracker mProfileTracker;

private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mFacebookCallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        Log.d("KeyHash", "onSuccess");
        AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        mTextDetails.setText(constructWelcomeMessage(profile));

    }


    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        Log.d("KeyHash", "onCancel");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException e) {
        Log.d("KeyHash", "onError " + e);
    }
};


public MainFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    setupTokenTracker();
    setupProfileTracker();

    mTokenTracker.startTracking();
    mProfileTracker.startTracking();
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setupTextDetails(view);
    setupLoginButton(view);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
    mTextDetails.setText(constructWelcomeMessage(profile));
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mTokenTracker.stopTracking();
    mProfileTracker.stopTracking();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

private void setupTextDetails(View view) {
    mTextDetails = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_details);
}

private void setupTokenTracker() {
    mTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldAccessToken, AccessToken currentAccessToken) {
            Log.d("KeyHash", "Welcome" + currentAccessToken);
        }
    };
}

private void setupProfileTracker() {
    mProfileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile currentProfile) {
            Log.d("KeyHash", "Welcome" + currentProfile);
            mTextDetails.setText(constructWelcomeMessage(currentProfile));
        }
    };
}

private void setupLoginButton(View view) {
    LoginButton mButtonLogin = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    mButtonLogin.setFragment(this);
    mButtonLogin.setReadPermissions("public_profile,user_friends,email");
    mButtonLogin.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, mFacebookCallback);
}

private String constructWelcomeMessage(Profile profile) {
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    if (profile != null) {
         stringBuffer.append("Welcome " + profile.getName());
    }
   return stringBuffer.toString();
}

}
```

Comment: Inside your   if (profile != null)  you can call other activity and can get details of the user in it

Comment: continues error :(

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to start an activity as soon as the user successfully logs in, you can call `startActivity(intent)` in the `onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult)` method of the FacebookCallback.

Comment: I used the code, startActivity( new Intent(MainFragment.this, HomeActivity.class)); -- more continues error

Answer (score 1):

try this in onSuccess method

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        accessToken,
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(
                                    JSONObject object,
                                    GraphResponse response) {
                                // Application code
                                try {

                                    String name = object.getString("name");
                                    String id = object.getString("id");

                                    Intent redirect=new Intent(Login_Activity.this,anotheractivity.class);
                                    startActivity(redirect);

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: "Error:(63, 49) error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(MainFragment,Class<HomeActivity>)
constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; MainFragment cannot be converted to String)
constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class<?>) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; MainFragment cannot be converted to Context)"

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27704006/error-using-onclicklistener-intent)