# An "ArrayAdapter" is not being set

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am trying to add `String` in a `ListView` but when creating an `ArrayAdapter` object getting this error :

```
Error:(32, 48) error: no suitable constructor found for ArrayAdapter(<anonymous OnClickListener>,int,List)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Context)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,String[]) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Context)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,List<String>) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Context)
```

What i am getting here is `<anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Context` but don't know how to fix it.

My code is :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView listView;
private static List listArray;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.itemList);
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            EditText itemNameView = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.itemName);
            String itemName = itemNameView.getText().toString();
            listArray.add(itemName);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listArray);
            adapter.add(itemName);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    });
}
```

}

and the error being throw for following line from above code :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listArray);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize Your list and do like this

```
 listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        listArray = new ArrayList();

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
                listArray.add(edittext.getText().toString().trim());
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ListviewMainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listArray);
                listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
```

Comment: but i am trying to take a string from `EditText` then add it to `ListView` everytime when a `Button` being Click.

Comment: so i choose to create `ArrayAdapter` in `onClickListener` of that `Button`. but `ArrayAdapter` throwing an error for `this` parameter. error `<anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Context`.

Comment: also add this line listArray = new ArrayList(); and clean project and then run

Comment: changed `MainActivity.this`  but not working. now it is being install but when opening being crash.

Comment: Thanks, now it is working. Would you please tell me about `MainActivity.this`. why only `this` parameter is not accepted here.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27704006/error-using-onclicklistener-intent

Answer (score 0):

Try this method it works. First you have to initialize the `ArrayList` and create the condition `if(!listdata.isEmpty())`.

```
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String data = edt.getText().toString();
            ArrayList<String> listdata = new ArrayList<String>();
            listdata.add(data);



            if(!listdata.isEmpty()){
              ArrayAdapter  adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listdata);
                list.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

        }
    });

}
```